# Pandas: How do I replace list items with a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of values:

```
Dict = {
       "KeyA":"ValueA",
       "KeyB":"ValueB",
       "KeyC":"ValueC"
       }
```

And I have a dataframe where the values in a column are lists:

```
index    Column  
0        ["KeyA", "KeyB"]
1        ["KeyB", "KeyC"]
2        ["KeyA", "KeyC"]
```

And I want returned:

```
index    Column  
0        ["ValueA", "ValueB"]
1        ["ValueB", "ValueC"]
2        ["ValueA", "ValueC"]
```

I have tried using the replace function:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].replace(Dict)
```

But this does not appear to work with lists.

Is there a simple way of replacing the list values with a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
d = {
    "KeyA":"ValueA",
    "KeyB":"ValueB",
    "KeyC":"ValueC"
    }

df['Column'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: [d[i] for i in x])
```

Output:

```
             Column
0  [ValueA, ValueB]
1  [ValueB, ValueC]
2  [ValueA, ValueC]
```

Also, naming your variables so similar to reserved names is bad karma.